# How to make pop up screen without images in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can you please tell me how to make this type of pop up?  I do not need to design own component in drawable.  I don't have much knowledge in Android.

1) First there is Title with blue background .

2) Second there is scrolling list view (without image) and buy button (without image).
    Is it possible?

I Googled it to find out if we can make own button like that with some style?

Here is my image[image]

Comment: do you _really_ want to create a pop-up in (out-dated) iPhone style...?

Comment: yes can you please give example with code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Dialog/Pop up in combination with a ListView you have to google that up because its a complex theme.
good look

Comment: can you please make some example

Answer (score 0):

Start from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. You have to implement your own custom dialog layout, likely using a ListView (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

Comment: can you make one simple example so that iwill understand

Comment: Everything is written in the first link I gave you. Read and follow the tutorial, specially section starting from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog. Then, if you still have a problem, ask for a specific thing/task you're not able to do.
My personal suggestion is to avoid the simple copy/paste of a solution but get the basics by yourself in order to understand and then master the topic.